# SQL copy post_title to post_content

Tags: mssql

Anyone know the SQL to copy 
post_title to post_content where post_content is empty
for all and only posts in wordpress

Thanks for any pointers in advance
Richard

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really about WordPress, however you want:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = post_title WHERE post_content= "" AND post_type = 'post';`

Comment: Thanks very much, Richard

Comment: I think `WERE` should be `WHERE`?

Comment: @Garconis good spot. I've updated the query - thank you.